# Certain controls won't get generated in aspx.designer.cs-file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a weird problem. I can't access some of my server controls from my codebehind. I've looked around and can only find answers for situations where you can't find ANY controls and I've tried all solutions I've found here on stack. re-creating designer file, deleting temp data, renaming controls etc. Nothing works.

The weird thing is that I can access every controller I put outside my `ListView` element. But everything inside will not get generated in my aspx.designer.cs file.

Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMid" runat="server">
    <h2><asp:Label ID="LabelCat" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h2>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldID" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <div class="list-group">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListViewSearch" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceWebsite" DataKeyNames="WebsiteID">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Darn</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <div class="row list-group-item">
                        <div class="">
                            <a href="<%# "http://" + Eval("url") %>" class="list-group-item lnk-content col-xs-4"><%# Eval("url") %></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <div>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("websiteId").ToString() %>' OnClick="up_click"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" style="color:green"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDown" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("websiteId").ToString() %>' OnCommand="down_click"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="color:red"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lbl-score">
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelScore" runat="server" Text="Score: "></asp:Label>
                                <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxySearch" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LabelRating" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("rating") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnUp" EventName="Click" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lbl-desc">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelDesc1" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("Description1") + " | "%> '></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelDesc2" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("Description2") %> '></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceWebsite" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WDBAPPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Website] WHERE ([categoryId] = @HFID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenFieldID" Name="HFID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

I know there is a lot of code but basically the controls "LabeCat", "HiddenFieldID", "ListViewSearch" and "SqlDataSourceWebsite" show up in my aspx.designer.cs-file, but no other controls do, in other words; **all controls before and after my `ListView` work fine**. What could be wrong here? So confused.

Comment: just try to clean, rebuild your solution and if this not work try to add hard coded it

Comment: I've tried this. If I hardcode the values in they just get removed when I build the solution again.

Comment: don't write your code in the aspx.designer.cs but write it in aspx.cs

Comment: That just gives me "does not exist in context".